# can´t handle PictureBox.DrawImage inside TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

```
img = Image.FromFile(@"images\dcw.png");
Graphics g = tabPanl.GetControlFromPosition(1, 1).CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(img,
      new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50),
      new Rectangle(img.Width / 2 - 25, img.Height / 2 - 25, 50, 50),
      GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

if i do this in PictureBox (placed only on form) it works fine but inside TableLayoutPanel it won´t

also tried

```
        Image img = Image.FromFile(@"images\dcw.png");
        int picBoxIndex = tabPanl.Controls.GetChildIndex(picBox1x1);
        Graphics g = tabPanl.Controls[picBoxIndex].CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage(img,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50),
            new Rectangle(img.Width / 2 - 25, img.Height / 2 - 25, 50, 50),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

also tried

```
        Image img = Image.FromFile(@"images\dcw.png");
        Graphics g = picBox1x1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage(img,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50),
            new Rectangle(img.Width / 2 - 25, img.Height / 2 - 25, 50, 50),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

so would shoul i do else

trying to build a boardgame, which paints graphics at runtime - different images by players choice

thx Tony

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually draws, but then `Paint` event clears it. If you want to make it persistant, you have to add your code to the Paint event of your PictureBox.

```
 Image img = Image.FromFile(@"images\dcw.png");
 int picBoxIndex = tabPanl.Controls.GetChildIndex(picBox1x1);
tabPanl.Controls[picBoxIndex].Paint += (s,e) =>{
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(img,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50),
            new Rectangle(img.Width / 2 - 25, img.Height / 2 - 25, 50, 50),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
};
```

However, why don't you use the PictureBox.BackgroundImage Property?

Answer (score 0):

well, i didn´t use BackgroundImage, because i was not able, to put a (loop)defined part of an image inside this backgroudimage; this was my thought too, but i also wasn´t able to handle that issue

i try the way by Paint-Event, thx so far --> it worked fine